# How do I select a child element by ID with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble selecting the text inside a span element that resides in another container.

The situation I'm trying to solve is on the page we might have 10-15 different addresses at a time (so I'm appending a record Id onto the div's ID when the page is created). I need to be able to select a specific one by an ID, and then find the individual address pieces inside it.

An example of the HTML Output would be as follows:

```
<div id="Address_1">
    <span id="Address">Some Address</span>
    <span id="City">Some City</span>
    <span id="State">Some State</span>
    <span id="Zip">Some Zip</span>
</div>

<div id="Address_2">
    <span id="Address">Some Address</span>
    <span id="City">Some City</span>
    <span id="State">Some State</span>
    <span id="Zip">Some Zip</span>
</div>
```

I've tried using the following (and many, many variations):

```
$("#Address_" + Id).children().find("#Address").text;
$("#Address_" + Id).find("span#Address").text;
$("#Address_" + Id).find("span").find("#Address").text;
```

(I also can use a class inside the spans instead of a ID, but I'd like to know how to do it by ID as well.)

I'm sure it's something very simple that I'm doing incorrectly but I can seem to figure it out. I've searched a lot of questions on here as well looking for a similar one but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I apologize in advance if I simply didn't search using the right phrasing.

Any and all help is very much appreciated.

UPDATE: Here is my solution, thanks to the help of Ken Redler.

```
<div id="Address_1">
    <span class="Address">Some Address</span>
    <span class="City">Some City</span>
    <span class="State">Some State</span>
    <span class="Zip">Some Zip</span>
</div>

$("#Address_" + Id).find("span.Address").text();
```

Comment: ID attribute values must be unique across the entire document. Also, if you are marking up addresses, maybe you should have a look at the hCard microformat

Comment: Thanks, I often forget about it being unique in html since it isn't "forced" like it is in code compilation (like Visual Studio). I'll look into the microformat you mentioned as well, but since this is a small internal application I don't know that it'd apply. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: +1 @Yi Jiang, though it's worth bearing in mind @Codinghorror's blog entry: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/microformats-boon-or-bane.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IDs must be unique across the whole document. You should make the "inner" IDs classes instead. Then you'd have:

```
$('#Address_'+Id).find('span.address').text();
```

As per LarsH's comment, in your document, where you have:

```
<div id="Address_1">
    <span id="Address">Some Address</span>
```

you'd change it to:

```
<div id="Address_1">
    <span class="Address">Some Address</span>
```

If there's more than one of a particular ID, your results will be unpredictable at best.

Comment: To clarify: your html should become

     <div id="Address_1">
         <span class="address">Some Address</span>
         <span class="city">Some City</span>

etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Ken. I knew it was something simple along those lines. I can change it to classes in this case, but if for some reason I did have to select by ID, how would I go about doing it in that instance?

Comment: Delebrin, if you have to select by ID, and there's more than one of the same ID on the page, it's not likely to work except by serendipity.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I just thought it may work since even though the IDs weren't unique across the entire document, they were unique inside the containing div. As I said though, I can change it to classes (and have) so it all works. Thanks again.

Comment: Delebrin, glad to help. I understand your thinking on the IDs being unique *in combination* -- which is why I hedged by saying it's not *likely* to work. It may, and it may not. It may work in some browsers but not others... etc.